# Error al crear array

Tags: array

Tengo el siguiente código en JS, que lee una base de datos de firebase y guarda el contenido en un arreglo array :

```js
const readDB = async () => {
  const userc = auth.currentUser;
  let flesson;
  let mylesson = {};
  let module = {};  
  let lesson;
  try {
    let arrlesson = [];
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "curso"));
    const lessons = querySnapshot.docs;   
    flesson = lessons[0].data().leccion;      
    lessons.forEach((doc) => {
      let data = doc.data();
      if (flesson != data.leccion) {         
        flesson = lesson;
        module = {
          lecciones: arrlesson,
          nombre: lesson
        };
        array.push(module);        
        arrlesson = [];          
      }
      lesson = data.leccion;        
      mylesson = {
        urlvideo: data.urlvideo,
        titulo: data.titulo,
        descripcion: data.descripcion
      };
      arrlesson.push(mylesson);        
    });
    module = {
      lecciones: arrlesson,
      nombre: lesson
    };
    array.push(module);    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("El error es: ", error); 
  }  
}
```

El problema es que me llena el array con los datos de la base de datos, pero cuando trato de acceder a los datos del array me dice que es undefined, yo imprimo el arreglo array y me lo imprime de forma correcta, pero cuando hago un "Console.log(array[0])" me imprime undefined y cuando hagop un "console.log(array.length)" me imprime 0, sin embargo el "console.log(array)" funciona bien y me imprime el contenido correcto del arreglo ¿por que sucede esto?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No aparece el código en su contexto. ¿Dónde están los `console.log` que mencionas? Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.